# Relationship between instances of List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, list

Is there any way to tell via reflection that a generic list of Type A is related to a generic list of Type B?  For example, I have a `List<string>` and a `List<int>`.  How can I tell via reflection that both these types are 'instances' of `List<T>`.  I think I'm having a problem because `List<T>` isn't a real type.  You can't do `typeof(List<T>)` for example.  `List<T>` is a compiler trick I guess.  So is there anyway to determine if two different types come from `List<T>`?

Comment: You should read about generics before writing code like that.

Comment: @alga what is wrong with the code? They are trying to learn more about generics and have asked a fantastic question that I doubt most .NET programmers know the answer to.

Comment: ok, guys, I'll explain what I meant. I think BowserKingKoopa has just started his career. It's very important to be able to find the information otherwise he will deadlock. Moreover every C# book or article contains this information. Can you imagine what would happen if nobody attempted to solve even the simplest of problems by themselves?
Don't think just about your points and badges, think a little bit deeply, what is better, an answer or an advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can... `List<>` is actually what's called an "unbound generic type" meaning it has not been parameterized with a type. When the type argument is specified it's called a "bound generic type". A type which involves "raw" type parameters, like `List<T>` is an "open generic type", and one that involves only actual types, like `List<int>` is a "closed generic type". The only situation in which an unbound generic type may be used in C# is in the typeof operator. To access the unbound type, or a closed type you would do:

```
Type listOfT = typeof(List<>); // unbound type
Type listOfString = typeof(List<string>); // closed bound type
Type listOfInt32 = typeof(List<int>); // closed bound type

Assert.IsTrue(listOfString.IsGenericType);

Assert.AreEqual(typeof(string), listOfString.GetGenericTypeParameters()[0]);
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(List<>), listOfString.GetGenericTypeDefinition());

Type setOfString = typeof(HashSet<string>);

Assert.AreNotEqual(typeof(List<>), setOfString.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
```

Comment: Ah Ok.  I see.  That seems to be working.  One problem I'm having though is that the Name of the Type object that comes back from List<> is 'System.RuntimeType'.  If I do the same thing for HashSet<T> I also get back a Type called 'System.RuntimeType'.  They are two different Type objects with the same name.  So how can I tell them apart?  I need to persist this info somewhere and I have nothing to persist since I don't get back a name like 'System.List<>' that I can understand.

Comment: Yes they are both RuntimeType in the same way that "hello".GetType() and 123.GetType() are both System.Type - but they represent two different types. You can examine the FullName property if you want but if you're trying to test if a particular type is listOfT then you should compare equality as shown above.

Comment: FullName also returns just 'System.RuntimeType'.  Since I can't get any unique name from the Types coming back from System.GetGenericTypeDefinition() I can't persist the fact that the Type came from a List<T>.  I'm trying to persist these types using their Names.  So two different Types with the same name is screwing me up.

Comment: I apologize to Marc for junking up his answer with comments. I'm jumping all over the place - I'll keep my comments under my own answer from now on. As I mentioned under Marc's answer I think you are going one level too deep. Try Console.WriteLine( typeof(List<>).FullName ) and Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<string>).FullName) and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I was printing out the value of the type name incorrectly accidentally.  You're right.  This is exactly what I need.  Thank you.

Comment: Though your point is well taken, your terminology is incorrect.  List<> is not an open generic type. List<int> is a *closed* generic type and a *bound* generic type.  List<T> is an *open* generic type and a *bound* generic type. List<> is an *unbound* generic type, not an *open* generic type.

Answer (score 5):

Actually `List<T>` *is* a real type in many ways (you can use `typeof(List<>)`, for example), and `List<T>` is **not** merely a compiler trick, but a runtime trick. But you can indeed check the open generic type, via something like:

```
    static Type GetRawType(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsGenericType ? type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : type;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
        Type type1 = GetRawType(list1.GetType()),
            type2 = GetRawType(list2.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(type1 == type2); // true
    }
```

Comment: GetGenericTypeDefinition() is always returning a Type of System.RuntimeType.  That's not exactly what I'm looking for.  I was expecting to get back 'System.List<T>' or something.  I'm sure lots of things are System.RuntimeType that have nothing to do with List<T>.  Am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase the question.  How can I tell if a given type comes from List<T>' ?

Comment: @Bowser, GetGenericTypeDefinition() is what you want. bool isListOfT = type.IsGenericType && (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>));

Comment: It's sort of what I want.  I get back a Type object but the .Name property of the Type object is 'System.RuntimeType'.  I need something more identifiable than that because I plan on persisting and then recreating these objects.  If I do GetGenericTypeDefinition() on a HashSet<T> I also get back a Type called 'System.RuntimeType'.  Sure it's a different Type than the one I got back from the List<T>.GetGenericTypeDefinition() but the name alone isn't enough information to know what generic type it really came from.

Comment: No, then you're going one level too deep. typeof(List<>).Name and typeof(List<string>).Name both return "List`1".

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right, I was going one level too deep.  Thank you.

Comment: @Josh thanks for fielding that; my train went out of signal range ;-p

Comment: I am relying on train tunnels and London fog to catch up to you and Jon Skeet. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
typeof(List<string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Call GetGenericTypeDefinition:

```
    List<string> l1 = new List<string>();
    List<int> l2 = new List<int>();
    Type t1 = l1.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    Type t2 = l2.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    Console.Write(t1 == t2);//output: true;
```